# How to indent the item in the theorem environment of ams-gsm package

Tags: lists, indentation

I use gsm package to write my latex file. Normally, in the theorem environment, the item are indented a small space from the left margin. I want to indent it all  to the left margin like the following picture:

[image]

Here is a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{gsm-l}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\begin{document}
\begin{theorem} This is the theorem.
\begin{enumerate}
\item The first item
\item The second item
\item Are they indented as my purpose?
\end{enumerate}
\end{theorem}
\end{document}
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This really has nothing to do with the `theorem` environment provided by the document class through `\newtheorem`. Instead, it's the default behaviour of a list (including `enumerate` and `itemize`). You can modify the indentation using some of [`enumitem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem)'s interfaces. Below I've set the `leftmargin` to be automatically calculated using `*`, which results in a flush-left setting:

[image]

```
\documentclass{gsm-l}
\usepackage{amsmath,enumitem}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{amsmath,enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate]{leftmargin=*}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\begin{document}
\begin{theorem} This is the theorem.
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item The first item
    \item The second item
    \item The third item that is a tad longer and should span more than 
      a single line, and naturally flow to a second line.
  \end{enumerate}
\end{theorem}
\end{document}
```

`\setlist[enumerate]` changes the default behaviour of `enumerate` at the document level, across all levels of nesting. If you wish to have a more localized change, you can supply an optional argument to the environment instead using the following interface:

```
\begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=*]
  ...
\end{enumerate}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It works. May I ask you another question? What should I do if I want to indent the item as the normal idented text? What does it mean by the parameter *?

Comment: @NguyễnDuyKhánh: You should really read the [`enumitem` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/enumitem/enumitem.pdf) - everything is explained there, plus additional options that you can use, together with examples. Experiment!

Comment: the labels on the enumerated items should really be upright, even in an otherwise italic setting like a theorem.

Answer (score 2):

document classes based on `amsbook` (including `gsm-l`) set up the indentation
to be too large, as observed here.

the mechanism used at ams to decrease it is to override the default margin settings,
which must be done `\AtBeginDocument`, since that is how they are initially defined:

```
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \labelsep=5pt\relax
  \setcounter{enumi}{13}\setcounter{enumii}{13}%
  \setcounter{enumiii}{13}\setcounter{enumiv}{13}%
  \settowidth\leftmargini{\labelenumi\hskip\labelsep}%
%%  \advance\leftmargini by \normalparindent % this is the culprit
  \settowidth\leftmarginii{\labelenumii\hskip\labelsep}%
  \settowidth\leftmarginiii{\labelenumiii\hskip\labelsep}%
  \settowidth\leftmarginiv{\labelenumiv\hskip\labelsep}%
  \setcounter{enumi}{0}\setcounter{enumii}{0}%
  \setcounter{enumiii}{0}\setcounter{enumiv}{0}%
  \leftmarginv=10pt  \leftmarginvi=\leftmarginv
  \leftmargin=\leftmargini
  \labelwidth=\leftmargini \advance\labelwidth-\labelsep
  \@listi}
```

since this is not set up as a command definition, it is not readily patched by
techniques defined in `etoolbox` as i understand it.